Suscribir a topico utilizando API de firebase - Cloud Messaging
Llevo varios días tratando de realizar la suscripción de un dispositivo hacia un tópico desde Postman a través de la API de Firebase, el problema es que varios ejemplos existentes corresponden a la versión antigua de Firebase, pero actualmente al utilizar HTTP v1 no me funciona nada, ni la API-key, ni la url... y al revisar la documentación me indica que dicha acción solo se puede a través de Node, Python, C#, java y GO.
Alguien ha podido realizar dicha suscripción utilizando postman directamente o cualquier otra aplicación para realizar solicitudes HTTP? hasta el momento he podido enviar notificaciones push desde postman sin problemas, pero me causa duda el que no haya información sobre la suscripción.
Siempre recibo el mensaje "Unathorized", ingresando la APIkey, el acces token y todo lo que indica la pagina.
Favor de su ayuda.
Saludos!


debes de agregar un header que te permitira acceder, el header es algo asi:
Authorization : key=[aqui_tu_token_de_Firebase]

Ahora que si esa url no te funciona, yo utilizo esta: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Jeovani Reyes, ya lo resolvi, la cabecera estaba bien, tenia ambos parametros que indicas y la url tambien estaba bien (la que tu me indicas me sirve para enviar notificaciones, más no crear topicos. El problema era que estaba obteniendo un token desde OAuth Token 2.0 y esta plataforma no agrega credenciales de acceso al proyecto, por lo que debo crear un token a partir del json que contiene las credenciales de acceso, en la pagina hay un ejemplo de como obtener dicho token usando java, node y python a partir de dicho archivo. Con esto, lo incorpore en la cabecera y todo ok.

Jeovani Reyes, ya lo resolvi, la cabecera estaba bien, tenia ambos parametros que indicas y la url tambien estaba bien (la que tu me indicas me sirve para enviar notificaciones, más no crear topicos. El problema era que estaba obteniendo un token desde OAuth Token 2.0 y esta plataforma no agrega credenciales de acceso al proyecto, por lo que debo crear un token a partir del json que contiene las credenciales de acceso, en la pagina hay un ejemplo de como obtener dicho token usando java, node y python a partir de dicho archivo. Con esto, lo incorpore en la cabecera en el parametro "Authorization" y todo funciono a la perfeccion.
